# '#' or '&' characters terminating C++ command line arguments

Tags: c++, special-characters, command-line-arguments

I have following problem:

When I have command line argument beginning with '&' or '#' character it does not count as argument, example:

```
~$ ./ircbot irc.felk.cvut.cz #ISAchannel 192.168.0.1
```

Now the argc = 2 (it should be 4)

```
~$ ./ircbot irc.felk.cvut.cz ISAchannel 192.168.0.1
```

Now the argc = 4 as it should be

Is this caused by shell recognizing these special characters or something ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `#` denotes the start of a comment (on many shells).

Comment: See http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell, `#` comments out the rest of the line. You'll have to escape it:

```
./ircbot irc.felk.cvut.cz \#ISAchannel 192.168.0.1
```

or

```
./ircbot irc.felk.cvut.cz '#ISAchannel' 192.168.0.1
```